# Why does aliyun OSS set the upload file size, but it still has the problem of exceeding the file size

Tags: alibaba-cloud-oss

[application.yml configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50qLs.png)

[Error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjZl0.png)

Nginx is also configured to upload files with a size of 50m，But more than 1M images, will upload failure, why？Help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try:

Before Spring Boot 2.0:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

After Spring Boot 2.0:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

Comment: Thank you, but the above image of application.yml configuration has been configured. You can click it to have a look

Comment: yes, i clicked and saw you have add  spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
, could u please add spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB this into you conf file, please have a try.